Google Docs plugin DocPress.it not linking to sites
Is anyone familiar with the Google Docs plugin called, "DocPress.it"?
If so, I am trying to understand why the plugin is not connecting to my WordPress site.
After installing the plugin in Google Docs and running the plugin, I click on the "Export" button.
I click on the "My own hosting" button, and the plugin does nothing.  It's supposed to allow me to connect to my WordPress site, but the preloader flashes for a second, then nothing.
I want to test this plugin out before purchasing a license.
Has anyone else encountered this problem?  If so, how did you resolve it?

This looks off-topic as it's unclear what the specific problem unique to programming is. It might be on topic in [webmasters.se].

I was able to link Docpress.it to another WordPress site without issue.  It appears that the site I was having problems with is the only problem site.  Aside from that, the plugin works fine.
